# Android - Unable to setup connection

Tags: android

This is the error that I am getting while building the app

> java.lang.NullPointerException: cancel() called with a null PendingIntent
>           at android.app.AlarmManager.cancel(AlarmManager.java:901)
>           at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.AlarmPingSender.stop(AlarmPingSender.java:86)
>           at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms.shutdownConnection(ClientComms.java:327)
>           at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:608)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Part of the code that is giving this error is

```
try {
                    client = new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), "ssl://192.168.43.112:1883", clientId);
                    InputStream input = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mynewkeystore);
                    options = new MqttConnectOptions();
                    options.setSocketFactory(client.getSSLSocketFactory(input,"password"));
                    IMqttToken token = client.connect(options);
                    token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                            //Log.d("Connection", "Connected to Broker ");
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ConnectiontoMQTTBrokerMade", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            pubConnect.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            pubDisconnect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pubPub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            ipinputpublish.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            messagemqtt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ConnectiontoMQTTBrokerRejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d("Connection", "Unable to connect to Broker");
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

I am unable to figure out why this error is being generated. Can someone please help me out here ?

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: this is inside an OnClickListener
other parts of the code have no relation to this

Comment: Are you showing relevant lines of code from the error I don't see org.eclipse.paho.android.service. 'AlarmPingSender' .stop(AlarmPingSender.java:86) or a pending intent

Comment: See The app is working till I press the button.
The code for that button is given below
Also the error might be thrown by a process

Comment: This is the entire code inside the clickAction.

Comment: Looks like crash inside the lib. You need to check that you set all configs correctly or use the lib functions properly. If no help, you may ask the creators of lib about this error. Code in onClick has nothing to do with this error.

Comment: Check https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android/issues/158 maybe it has your solution in short change version to 1.1.1